# ASP.NET C# Generate a create table statement

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create a c# statement which creates a table.

Below is my current query:

```
    string user = (User.Identity.Name);

    string db = user+["-Result"] + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
```

I am trying to create a table of name which will be something like `Jane-Result2011111111`

I am able to create the table when my statement did not include the name :

`user+"Result" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");`

May I know how can I include the `-` in my statement?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried: `string db = user+ "Result" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");` - without percent sign?

Comment: It could be the `-` between Name and Result that is causing problems for you. Try without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

Ok, you re-tagged and edited your question after my first answer.  Try moving the brackets inside of the quotes (or remove them all together).

`string db = user + "[-Result]" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");`

There are better ways in C# to combine strings though.  One is `String.Format`.

```
string db = String.Format("{0}-Result{1}", user, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss"));
```

**Original answer**

Not sure what language the code is in (C#?), but I'm guessing you need a `+` between your 2nd double quote and the word user.

`string db = "'%" + user + "%'Result" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");`

Answer (score 1):

```
user + "-Result" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `%` symbol, that's a wildcard for the `LIKE` operator and should not be used in identifiers.

Replace the `%` with `#` and you should be fine.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa274626(v=sql.80).aspx

**edit**
After you changed your question the updated answer is:

```
string db = user+"_Result" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
```

Don't use the `[` and replace the `-` with a `_`.

Oh and don't change the question so that answers become useless.

Comment: thank you for the help, but it still says incorrect syntax near '-'

Answer (score 0):

The Minus (-) ist not allowed in a table name, you may use the Underscore. Read the Rules for regular Identifiers [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can delimit your table name using either double quotes or square brackets:

```
string db = "[" + user + "-Result" + "]"
    + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
```

See the SQL Server docs on [Delimited Identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176027.aspx) for more info.

Also note that this code might be vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953.aspx) attacks if the username is tampered to include malicious code.  Consider using [SMO](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/olivier_pieri/archive/2004/12/07/277501.aspx) instead instead of executing raw `CREATE TABLE` SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with other commentators that creating a table per user may not be a great design, you can write your statement more succintly:

string db = String.Format("[{0}-Result{1}]", user, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss"));

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

The best reference for database object names is:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx

This tells you that the special characters allowed in un-delimited object names does not include `-` which is why it is failing. You can either use an underscore instead (which is a valid character) or escape it by enclosing the entire object in square brackets. Either of these will work.

And there is probably a design problem if you are creating lots of tables dynamically. Are you sure you wouldn't be better off just expanding the schema to include a date and user column and then including it all in one table and using a where clause to get data rather than dynamically generating table names?